# Wikidata Query Service - Incomplete Result: Wikipedia URL missing

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am using the Wikidata Query Service (https://query.wikidata.org) to obtain the (former) spouses of Daniel Craig with this query:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?s ?sLabel ?s_wpurl1 ?s_wpurl2 WHERE {
?s wdt:P26 wd:Q4547 .
OPTIONAL {
?s_wpurl1 schema:about ?s .
?s_wpurl1 schema:inLanguage "en" .
FILTER (SUBSTR(str(?s_wpurl1), 1, 25) = "https://en.wikipedia.org/")
} .
OPTIONAL {
?s_wpurl2 schema:about ?s .
?s_wpurl2 schema:inLanguage "de" .
FILTER (SUBSTR(str(?s_wpurl2), 1, 25) = "https://de.wikipedia.org/")
} .
SERVICE wikibase:label {
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
}
}
```

As expected, the result set consists of two results: Q134077 (Rachel Weisz) and Q62510 (Heike Makatsch).

But the requested en. and de.wikipedia article urls are only listed for Rachel Weisz, although respective articles exist for Heike Makatsch and are linked to the item representing Makatsch (see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q62510).

The urls for that item are also not listed in other queries (where other items' urls are listed), so the problem is the item and not the query.

Why are wikipedia article urls missing in a SPARQL result set for an item where this information exists?

**Update**:

Now (a day later) the service is returning the urls.

Does anybody know when the service is expected to leave beta status and to become fully reliable?

Comment: Hi Paul, are you still seeing the same problem? I ran the query in Wikidata and its returning the two correct Heike Makatsch URLs.

Comment: You're right, now it's returning the URLs. Good to know the service isn't fully reliable yet, that's why it's still called Wikidata Query Service **Beta** I quess. Anyway, it's a great service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query service had the [problem of missing sitelinks](https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikidata-tech/2015-October/000885.html) due to faulty data loading. It was fixed, so now the links should be fine.